# LDAP bind associations with subsequent requests

Tags: ldap, bind

I'm wondering how LDAP associates requests with a previous BIND request on a technical level.

For example you issue a BIND request to LDAP that authenticates you to do searches or whatever then you UNBIND.

How does LDAP associate your subsequent SEARCH/ADD etc. requests after the BIND?

I'm currently digging through a packet capture of a bunch of LDAP requests and I don't see the bindResponses returning a session token or anything like that ... does it just consider an IP authenticated or something?

Thanks if anyone can shed some light on the internal mechanism here!

edit: using SIMPLE auth BINDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking to the LDAP server using UDP or TCP?

With TCP, it's simple - you do a BIND, then that TCP connection remains authenticated for any subsequent operations issued on the connection, until the connection closes or you issue an UNBIND.